# 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'sem'

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

I have a time series working on, and extracting features from it via the sliding window method. I exactly run the example [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sem.html#pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sem) using google colaboratory :

```
s = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3])
s.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sem()
```

and the output is :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ec5250a57afe> in <module>()
      1 s = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3])
----> 2 s.rolling(2, min_periods=1).sem()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/window/rolling.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    261 
    262         raise AttributeError(
--> 263             f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
    264         )
    265 

AttributeError: 'Rolling' object has no attribute 'sem'
```

can anyone help what is the problem? the version of pandas I am using is : 1.1.5

Comment: May be `pandas` 1.1.5 does not have this functionality of `sem` so please upgrade the package

Comment: Available in [1.2.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.0.html?#other-enhancements)+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to install latest `pandas` module by upgrading it

`pip install pandas -U`

or

`pip install pandas --upgrade`